# How to write user defined average function in oracle

Tags: oracle, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a user defined avg function, e.g. to calculate an average, sum or count - are there any examples I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Aldridge mentioned, the "official" way to build a user-defined aggregate function is to use Oracle Data Cartridge.  But in my experience, it is simpler, faster, and less buggy to use the `CAST(COLLECT` method.  The only downside is your SQL statement requires some extra syntax.

For example, to create a custom average function that ignores the number 1:

```
--Created nested table of numbers
create or replace type number_nt is table of number;

--Create a custom average function.
--For example, average everything except the number "1".
create or replace function my_avg(numbers number_nt) return number is
    v_sum number := 0;
    v_count number := 0;
begin
    --Sum and count all the values, excluding nulls and "1".
    for i in 1 .. numbers.count loop
        if numbers(i) is not null and numbers(i) <> 1 then
            v_sum := v_sum + numbers(i);
            v_count := v_count + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;

    if v_count = 0 then
        return null;
    else
        return v_sum/v_count;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Here's how to call the function:

```
--Regular average is 2, our custom average that excludes 1 should be 2.5.
select
    avg(test_value) avg
    ,my_avg(cast(collect(test_value) as number_nt)) my_avg
from
(
    select 1 test_value from dual union all
    select 2 test_value from dual union all
    select 3 test_value from dual
);

AVG  MY_AVG
--   ------
2    2.5
```

Comment: +1: Especially handy for being able to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY in the COLLECT function as well I should think. Do you know what the minimum version is for that?

Comment: @DavidAldridge COLLECT was introduced in 10g.  DISTINCT and ORDER BY were officially added in 11g, but they appear to work fine in 10g.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the [User Defined Aggregates Function Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/ext_agg_ref.htm), documented in the Data Cartridge Developers' Guide.

Some examples are documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm#CECJAAJG).

Comment: i dnt understand this coz i am new or oracle plz give some simple example here

Comment: Another example (article) [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jul/o46sql-083623.html)